If I want when an input field to choose date of birth is min 13 year old the form will submit or not show error
I want an input field with DOB; if age is max 13, then form will be submitted, or if more than 13 years, the form will not be submitted and show error that you are not qualified.
My code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Form1.css';

function Form1() {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        file: null,
        number: '',
        DOB: '',
        gender: '',
        username: '',
        password: '',
        repassword: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        zip: '',
        country: '',
        address: ''
    });

    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState({});
    const [submissions, setSubmissions] = useState([]);
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    const [currentEditIndex, setCurrentEditIndex] = useState(null);

    const calculateAge = (dob) => {
        const birthDate = new Date(dob);
        const today = new Date();
        let age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        const monthDifference = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (monthDifference < 0 || (monthDifference === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    };

    const validateField = (name, value) => {
        let error = '';
        const nameRegex = /^[A-Za-z\s]{2,50}$/;
        const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        const phoneRegex = /^[6-9]\d{9}$/;
        const passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/;
        const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,20}$/;
        const addressRegex =  /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,100}$/;
        const zipRegex = /^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$/;
        const cityRegex =  /^[A-Za-z\s]{3,30}$/;
        const stateRegex = /^[A-Za-z\s]{2,20}$/;
        const countryRegex = /^[A-Za-z\s]{5,60}$/;

        switch (name) {
            case 'name':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Name is required!';
                } else if (!nameRegex.test(value)) {
                    error = 'Please enter a valid name (2-50 alphabetic characters).';
                }
                break;
            case 'email':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Email is required!';
                } else if (!emailRegex.test(value)) {
                    error = 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                }
                break;
            case 'file':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'File is required';
                } else if (!['image/jpeg', 'image/png'].includes(value.type) || value.size > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
                    error = 'Please upload a valid file (jpg/png) with size up to 5MB.';
                }
                break;
            case 'number':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Please enter a valid number!';
                } else if (!phoneRegex.test(value)) {
                    error = 'Please enter a valid Indian phone number (10 digits).';
                }
                break;
            case 'DOB':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Please enter your date of birth';
                } else if (calculateAge(value) < 13) {
                    error = 'You must be at least 13 years old.';
                }
                break;
            case 'gender':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Please select your gender';
                }
                break;
            case 'username':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Username is required!';
                } else if (!usernameRegex.test(value)) {
                    error = 'Please enter a valid username (3-20 alphanumeric characters).';
                }
                break;
            case 'password':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Password is required';
                } else if (!passwordRegex.test(value)) {
                    error = 'Password must be at least 8 characters long and include at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character.';
                }
                break;
            case 'repassword':
                if (value !== formData.password) {
                    error = 'Passwords do not match.';
                }
                break;
                case 'city':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Please enter your city.';
                }
                 else if(!cityRegex.test(value)) {
                   error = 'Please enter a valid city name  (3-30 alphabetic characters).'; 
                }
                break;
            case 'state':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Please enter your state or province.';
                } else if (!stateRegex.test(value)) {
                  error = 'Please enter a valid state name  (2-20 alphabetic characters).'
                }
                break;
            case 'zip':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Zip/Postal is required';
                }
                 else if(!zipRegex.test(value)) {
                   error = 'Please enter a valid Zip/Postal (6 digits).'; 
                }
                break;
            case 'country':
                if (!value) {
                    error = 'Please enter your country.';
                } else if (!countryRegex.test(value)) {
                    error = "Please enter a valid country name  (2-60 alphabetic characters)."
                }
                break;
                case 'address':
                    if (!value) {
                        error = 'Please enter a valid address.';
                    } else if(!addressRegex.test(value)) {
                       error = 'Please enter a valid address (5-100 alphanumeric character)'; 
                    }
                    break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return error;
    };

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value, type, files } = e.target;
        const newValue = type === 'file' ? files[0] : value;
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name]: newValue
        });

        const error = validateField(name, newValue);
        setErrorMessage({
            ...errorMessage,
            [name]: error
        });
    };

    const validateForm = (values) => {
        const errors = {};
        for (let field in values) {
            const error = validateField(field, values[field]);
            if (error) {
                errors[field] = error;
            }
        }
        return errors;
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const errors = validateForm(formData);
        if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
            if (isEditing) {
                const updatedSubmissions = submissions.map((submission, index) =>
                    index === currentEditIndex ? formData : submission
                );
                setSubmissions(updatedSubmissions);
                setIsEditing(false);
                setCurrentEditIndex(null);
            } else {
                setSubmissions([...submissions, formData]);
            }
            localStorage.setItem('submissions', JSON.stringify([...submissions, formData]));
            alert('Form submitted successfully!');
            handleReset();
        } else {
            setErrorMessage(errors);
        }
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        setFormData({
            name: '',
            email: '',
            file: null,
            number: '',
            DOB: '',
            gender: '',
            username: '',
            password: '',
            repassword: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zip: '',
            country: '',
            address: ''
        });
        setErrorMessage({});
    };

    const handleEdit = (index) => {
        setFormData(submissions[index]);
        setIsEditing(true);
        setCurrentEditIndex(index);
    };

    const handleDelete = (index) => {
        const updatedSubmissions = submissions.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
        setSubmissions(updatedSubmissions);
        localStorage.setItem('submissions', JSON.stringify(updatedSubmissions));
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Form</h1>
                <fieldset>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Row className="">
                            <Col xs={12} >
                                <Row className="g-3 mb-6">
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="name">Name*</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                                            value={formData.name} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.name && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.name}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="email">Email*</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                                            value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.email && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.email}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="file">File*</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder="Upload Your File"
                                            onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.file && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.file}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="number">Phone Number*</label>
                                        <input type="tel" maxLength={10} name="number" id="number" placeholder="Your Contact"
                                            value={formData.number} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.number && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.number}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="DOB">DOB*</label>
                                        <input type="date" name="DOB" id="DOB" placeholder="Date of Birth"
                                            value={formData.DOB} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.DOB && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.DOB}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="username">UserName*</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="UserName"
                                            value={formData.username} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.username && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.username}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="password">Password*</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password"
                                            value={formData.password} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.password && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.password}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="repassword">Re-password*</label>
                                        <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                            value={formData.repassword} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.repassword && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.repassword}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="city">City*</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Enter City Name"
                                            value={formData.city} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.city && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.city}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="state">State/Province*</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="State/Province"
                                            value={formData.state} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.state && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.state}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="zip">Zip/Postal Code*</label>
                                        <input type="tel" maxLength={7} name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip/Postal"
                                            value={formData.zip} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.zip && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.zip}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <label htmlFor="country">Country*</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Enter Country Name"
                                            value={formData.country} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.country && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.country}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <label htmlFor="gender">Gender*</label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" className='radio'
                                        checked={formData.gender === 'Male'} onChange={handleChange} required />Male
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" className='radio'
                                        checked={formData.gender === 'Female'} onChange={handleChange} required />Female
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="Other" className='radio'
                                        checked={formData.gender === 'Other'} onChange={handleChange} required />Other  
                                    {errorMessage.gender && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.gender}</p>}
                                    <Col sm={6} md={12}>
                                        <label htmlFor="address">Address*</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Your Address"
                                            value={formData.address} onChange={handleChange} required />
                                        {errorMessage.address && <p className="error text-danger">{errorMessage.address}</p>}
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <button type="button" onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                        <button type="submit">{isEditing ? 'Update' : 'Submit'}</button>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </form>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <br /><br />
            <div className='contain-table'>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No.</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone No.</th>
                            <th>DOB</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>UserName</th>
                            <th>City</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th colSpan={2} className="text-center">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {submissions.map((submission, index) => (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                <td>{submission.name}</td>
                                <td>{submission.email}</td>
                                <td>{submission.number}</td>
                                <td>{submission.DOB}</td>
                                <td>{submission.gender}</td>
                                <td>{submission.username}</td>
                                <td>{submission.city}</td>
                                <td>{submission.country}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button onClick={() => handleEdit(index)} className="button">Edit</button>
                                    <button onClick={() => handleDelete(index)} className="button">Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Form1;

I want it such that when I fill the input and if I wrong it not show that time but when I fill another and first input filling wrong than error can show?

The code you shared seem like alot, try to streamline it to show only code that is particular to the issue you want to resolve.
